# No video feed in Zoom installed through Snap

Tags: snap, webcam, zoom-meeting

I've installed the Zoom client through Snap on my laptop with Kubuntu 20.04 but there's no video from the camera.

`zoom-client        5.9.6.2225                  170    latest/stable  ogra`

This is a relatively new machine, so I've never used Zoom on it before, but I was using it on my previous laptop with Kubuntu 16.04 with no problems (can't remember which version).

I realised the problem when I tried to join a meeting and there was no video. Now, if I go to *Settings* > *Video*, **the camera is recognised** by Zoom (it shows up as "Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate"), but it just shows **a black screen instead of the video feed**.

Please note that this behaviour is different to when the camera is not available. For example, if I disable the camera with `modprobe -r uvcvideo`, no cameras show up in Zoom settings, and the video window is greyed out.

Also, the camera itself and snap's access to it seem to be fine: it works fine on things like Google Meet and Skype, which is also installed via snap.

Any searches I tried on the Web only return generic/irrelevant results ("is the camera plugged in?" etc.).

Anybody has experience with this problem? Is there anything I could do to investigate further and get more details to identify the root of the problem?